# Summing very large numbers without using toolboxes

Tags: matlab, floating-point, addition, approximation, largenumber

I am trying to sum very large numbers in MATLAB, such as `e^800` and `e^1000` and obtain an answer.

I know that in Double-Precision, the largest number I can represent is `1.8 * 10^308`, otherwise I get Inf, which I am getting when trying to sum these numbers.

My question is, how do I go about estimating an answer for sums of very, very large numbers like these *without* using `vpa`, or some other toolbox?

Should I use strings? It is possible to do this using logs? Can I represent the floats as `m x 2^E` and if so, how do I take a number such as `e^700` and convert it to that? If the number is larger than the threshold for Inf, should I divide it by two, and store it in two different variables?

For example, how would I obtain an approximate answer for:

`e^700 + e^800 + e^900 + e^1000` ?

Comment: Maybe you want to use symbolic math? There is no way to encode such large numbers easily, and it's even harder to encode the sum of numbers with such large difference in magnitude. Are you sure you really need to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `vpa` ? Too slow ? It's the only built-in variable-precision arithmetic engine available.

Comment: exp(1000) + exp(900) + exp(800) + exp(700) = exp(1000) * ( 1 + exp(-100) + exp(-200) + exp(-300)) so with a relative error of the order of exp(-100) the sum is exp(1000)

Comment: It's more an exercise of whether I can do it without using any additional toolboxes. I know that I can use vpa or symbolic or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

A possible approximation is to use the rounded values of these numbers (I personally used [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=round%28e%5E900%29)), then perform "long addition" as they teach in elementary school:

```matlab
function sumStr = q57847408()
% store rounded values as string:
e700r = "10142320547350045094553295952312676152046795722430733487805362812493517025075236830454816031618297136953899163768858065865979600395888785678282243008887402599998988678389656623693619501668117889366505232839133350791146179734135738674857067797623379884901489612849999201100199130430066930357357609994944589";
e800r = "272637457211256656736477954636726975796659226578982795071066647118106329569950664167039352195586786006860427256761029240367497446044798868927677691427770056726553709171916768600252121000026950958713667265709829230666049302755903290190813628112360876270335261689183230096592218807453604259932239625718007773351636778976141601237086887204646030033802";
e900r = "7328814222307421705188664731793809962200803372470257400807463551580529988383143818044446210332341895120636693403927733397752413275206079839254190792861282973356634441244426690921723184222561912289431824879574706220963893719030715472100992004193705579194389741613195142957118770070062108395593116134031340597082860041712861324644992840377291211724061562384383156190256314590053986874606962229";
e1000r = "197007111401704699388887935224332312531693798532384578995280299138506385078244119347497807656302688993096381798752022693598298173054461289923262783660152825232320535169584566756192271567602788071422466826314006855168508653497941660316045367817938092905299728580132869945856470286534375900456564355589156220422320260518826112288638358372248724725214506150418881937494100871264232248436315760560377439930623959705844189509050047074217568";

% pad to the same length with zeros on the left:
padded = pad([e700r; e800r; e900r; e1000r], 'left', '0');

% convert the padded value to an array of digits:
dig = uint8(char(padded) - '0');

% some helpful computations for later:
colSum = [0 uint8(sum(dig, 1))]; % extra 0 is to prevent overflow of MSB
remainder = mod(colSum, 10);
carry = idivide(colSum, 10, 'floor');

while any(carry) % can also be a 'for' loop with nDigit iterations (at most)
  result = remainder + circshift(carry, -1);
  remainder = mod(result, 10);
  carry = idivide(result, 10, 'floor');
end

% remove leading zero (at most one):
if ~result(1)
  result = result(2:end);
end

% convert result back to string:
sumStr = string(char(result + '0'));
```

This gives the (rounded) result of:

```
197007111401704699388887935224332312531693805861198801302702004327171116872054081548301452764017301057216669857236647803717912876737392925607579016038517631441936559738211677036898431095605804172455718237264052427496060405708350697523284591075347592055157466708515626775854212347372496361426842057599220506613838622595904885345364347680768544809390466197511254544019946918140384750254735105245290662192955421993462796807599177706158188
```

Answer (score 0):

Typos fixed from before.

Decimal Approximation:

```
function [m, new_exponent] = base10_mantissa_exponent(base, exponent)
    exact_exp = exponent*log10(abs(base));
    new_exponent = floor(exact_exp);
    m = power(10, exact_exp - new_exponent);
end
```

So the value e<sup>600</sup> would become 3.7731 * 10<sup>260</sup>.

And the value 117<sup>150</sup> would become 1.6899 * 10<sup>310</sup>.

To add these two values together, I took the difference between the two exponents and divided the mantissa of the smaller term by it. Then it's just as simple as adding the mantissas together.

```
mantissaA = 3.7731;
exponentA = 260;
mantissaB = 1.6899;
exponentB = 310;

diff = abs(exponentA - exponentB);
if exponentA < exponentB
    mantissaA = mantissaA / (10^diff);
    finalExponent = exponentB;
elseif exponentB < exponentA
    mantissaB = mantissaB / (10^diff);
    finalExponent = exponentA;
end

finalMantissa = mantissaA + mantissaB;
```

This was important for me as I was performing sums such as:

(Σ e<sup>x</sup>) / (Σ xe<sup>x</sup>)

From x=1 to x=1000.